# I created function to focus but a Validate function runs first? Using DOMLoaded Content

Tags: javascript

I have created a function to re-focus on an input box if an invalid entry is put in. However, when I click on the input box it runs the `validate()` function. It does focus thereafter but it is running the function before it should be. I am sure I am doing something wrong, however, I am still grappling with how DOM-loaded content work.

I have copied the code below:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById("principal").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    validate();
  });
})

function validate() {
  var num = document.myform.num.value;
  if (isNaN(num) || num == 0 || num < 0 || num == null) {
    alert("Please enter a valid entry")
    document.getElementsById("principal").focus();
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" onsubmit="validate()">
  Amount <input name="num" id="principal" onsubmit=""><br/> </form>
<br>
```

Comment: Why not running the function on change event?

Comment: Thanks Mario, however, It just loops it again.

Comment: Also why access the field by name AND id? Just use one

Comment: Why on "click" event? There are people who just use the keyboard alone... Seems the wrong event for the job.

Comment: BTW, your snippet produces an error because you have a spelling mistake in `getElement[s]ById`.

Comment: thanks for that, I have changed its to change but still doesn't work.

Comment: You should not use `alert` ... bad practice.

Comment: Alert is not a choice it is part of the course direction.

Answer (score 1):

Use change event and don't use alert. It is really annoying. Since you insist, I added it back in when submitting

preventDefault is only needed on submit

```js
const validate = (e) => {
  const field = document.getElementById("principal");
  const num = field.value;
  const err = document.getElementById(field.id+"Error");
  err.setAttribute("hidden",true);
  if (isNaN(num) || num == 0 || num < 0 || num == null) {
    field.focus();
    field.select();
    if (e.type==="submit") { 
      alert(err.textContent)
      e.preventDefault()
    }  
    else  err.removeAttribute("hidden");
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.getElementById("principal").addEventListener('change', validate)
  document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener('submit', validate)
})
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  Amount <input name="principal" id="principal" required> <span id="principalError" hidden>Please enter a valid entry</span><br/>
</form>
```

Even simpler:

```html
<form name="myform">
  Amount <input name="num" id="principal" type="number" min="1" required autocomplete="off"/>
</form>
```

Added to your calculator

```js
const highlight = str => `<span class="highlight">${str}</span>`;
const currency = num => new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD'
}).format(num);

const getFutureValue = (principal, rate, year) => {
  var interest = rate / 100 + 1;
  return currency(principal * Math.pow(interest, year))
}

const compute = () => {
  // Ensure all values are _numbers_
  p = +document.getElementById("principal").value;
  r = +document.getElementById("rate").value;
  n = +document.getElementById("years").value;

  const newDate = new Date();
  newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + n);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `If you deposit ${highlight(currency(p))} at an interest rate of ${highlight(r+"%")},<br>
  you will receive an amount of ${highlight(getFutureValue(p, r, n))} in the year ${highlight(newDate.getFullYear())}`;

};


const validate = (e) => {
  const submitting = e.type === "submit"
  if (submitting) e.preventDefault()
  const field = document.getElementById("principal");
  const num = field.value;
  const err = document.getElementById(field.id + "Error");
  err.setAttribute("hidden", true);
  if (isNaN(num) || num == 0 || num < 0 || num == null) {
    field.focus();
    field.select();
    if (submitting)alert(err.textContent)
    else err.removeAttribute("hidden");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.getElementById("principal").addEventListener('change', validate)
  document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    if (validate(e)) compute(); // pass the event
  })
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#rate,
#years {
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  $<input type="number" id="principal" /> at <input type="number" id="rate" />% for <input type="number" id="years" /> years
  <br/><span id="principalError" hidden>Please enter a valid amount</span>

  <button id="compute">Compute Interest</button>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: This method removes the alert function which is necessary for my project.

Comment: Ok, I added the alert when submitting

Comment: Thank you my friend

Comment: I cannot get it to work inside my simple interest calculator?

Comment: @IK1987 I added it to your calculator